# Confusing lag situation - UIBezierPath re-draw going too slaw

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I've got a "SLATE2" tablet that allows me to write on a tablet with a special pen and interact with my own app. I'm having some trouble though, and I don't think it's a problem with hardware.

```
- (void)touchesBegan: (CGPoint)point
{
    [path moveToPoint:point];
}

- (void)touchesMoved: (CGPoint)point
{
    [path addLineToPoint: point]; // (4)
    [Newpath appendPath: path];
    pathTwo = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    pathTwo = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:Newpath.CGPath];
    pathTwo = [pathTwo fitInto: self.bounds];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)touchesEnded: (CGPoint)point
{
    pathTwo = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    pathTwo = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:Newpath.CGPath];
    pathTwo = [pathTwo fitInto: self.bounds];
    [path removeAllPoints];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[UIColor whiteColor] setStroke];
    [pathTwo stroke];
    return;
}
```

The drawing to the UIView screen is far too slow. I'm looking at the console and the events being raised by the actual tablet are at almost lightspeed. If there is a better way to draw on this UIView faster please show me.

I've dscovered the issue. fitInto is called so frequently and pathTwo is re-drawn every time. I need fitInto to be called everytime theres a new part of the pad that's drawn on to scale how much is shown.

I tried turning off anti-aliasing but that didn't work.

fitInto works like so...

imagine the screen of the iphone
and if you were to draw on a tablet, a square tablet, at the bottom, say a circle, if you were to draw a circle, it would just zoom in on the iphone screen as its the only drawing on the tablet. if you draw at the top of the tablet, the circle at the bottom is now shown to scale of the entire tablet because of the two opposing ends. i don't think this function could be made any faster... but let's try!

```
  func fit(into:CGRect) -> Self {
    let bounds = self.cgPath.boundingBox

    let sw     = into.size.width/bounds.width
    let sh     = into.size.height/bounds.height


    let factor = min (5, min(sw, max(sh, 0.0)))

    return scale(x: factor, y: factor, into: into)
  }
```

and here is scale

```
 func scale(x:CGFloat, y:CGFloat, into: CGRect? = nil) -> Self{
    var transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: x, y: y)

    if into != nil {
      transform = transform.concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: into!.midX - self.cgPath.boundingBox.midX, y: into!.midY - self.cgPath.boundingBox.midY))
    }
    let _ = applyCentered(transform: transform)

    return self
  }
```

Comment: You say 'I've got a "SLATE2" tablet that allows me to write on a tablet with a special pen and interact with my own app.' I don't understand. You're using an external hardware device attached to an iPhone/iPad? An iPad **IS** a tablet, so why do you need an external device?

Comment: Also, you are using the `Objective-C` tag, but the code you posted is Swift. Shouldn't you use the Swift tag instead?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked how many points are actually in your path?  I don't think you want to draw your CGPath pixel by pixel.  Instead you should only add a segment when the distance exceeds a certain threshold.  You can also simplify the path by drawing curves through the points instead of drawing line segments.  See this [primer on bezier curves](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/).

**EDIT**: The [Ray Wenderlich sample app](https://www.raywenderlich.com/87899/make-simple-drawing-app-uikit-swift) looks like its actually doing the same thing, adding points in TouchedMoved.  However in touchesEnded they rasterize the curve into a bitmap.  I'm not so sure that that will help your case though because it looks like you are deleting all of the points in touchesEnded.  I would still look at their code and see if you have any other points that could be a bottle neck.

Comment: I am doing it pixel by pixel to avoid inconsistencies - perhaps you can show me an example of how to add a segment when the distance exceeds a certain threshold?

Comment: If you are doing it pixel by pixel then store a bitmap and not a vector.  For a threshold store the current point in touches began.  compare the distance between current and new in touches moved.  if its greater than threshold then add a new point and set current = new, else return.

Comment: Can I use a bitmap with UIBezierPath?

Comment: No.  a path is a vector not a bitmap.

Comment: Ok. I can't use a bitmap because of a scale function I have that only works with a UIBezierPath. Do I have other options here about speeding up my operations?

Comment: I've tried a threshold of 15points. Still lags too much. Maybe if I show you my scaling function you can help further?

Comment: There should be no scaling function.  If you need to scale the curve you use the transform matrix on the CGContext.  There is a utility function to scale the matrix: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1454659-cgcontextscalectm?language=objc

Comment: I need to use a function of mine to scale the drawing according to how much of the SLATE is used.

Comment: No you don't.  You abosolutely should not do this.  The transform matrix is hardware accelerated.  There is no way your function is faster.  Take it out and see if that fixes the problem.  If so reimplement scaling using the transform matrix.

Answer (score 0):

What effect are you after? Are you trying to let the user trace lines and curves with the pen, or dots if they tap?

The simple fact is that iOS is not fast enough to track the user's pen/finger strokes point-by-point. Instead, you want to collect a series of points and create a UIBezierPath that connects those points with line segments. That will give you something pretty close to what you want. However, if the user traces fast, that will lag behind as well.